# Autocompletion does not work correctly in the colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have an issue with the colab. When i use autocomplete (using tab) i get irrelevant options. Can anybody explain how to make it work properly? Using tab in functions produces correct information about functions.

How it works in the colab:
list.[%%!, abs, ...]

How it should work: list.[append, copy, ...]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, now fixed. Issue: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/390